# Push new values after creation

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Reading IntroToRx website, it discourages using of Subject in favour of Observable.Create helper method.

As I can see, the OnNext method can be called only into subscribe method, because it's the only part I have access Observer object.

What if I would like to push new values after it's creation?
Am I "forced" to use a Subject?

Comment: explain more about what you're trying to achieve

Comment: depends on what is that you're 'pushing' - a bit simplified - if you're just handling other source's events, data (re-processing them and passing forward), then Subject can be avoided (and that line is a bit 'thin', you may not think but some external source is usually there). If you're actually making your own 'feed' of e.g. messages, w/o an apparent external source - then Subject will come up as a solution sooner or later. For details it's best to check the actual Rx source, to see how 'original creators' have gone solving some things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just exploring Rx, go for it - use Subjects, go nuts, see how they work, discover their pros and cons for yourself, then come back here and read the questions discussing why Subject is frowned upon.

Subjects offer a **much easier** way of "quickly bootstrapping" ideas and complicated Rx scenarios without needing to replicate the actual source conditions.

That said, they *do* inject state into what is kinda-sorta-supposed-to-be a stateless chain of operations, so be careful not to rely on them.

So, to sum up: if you are trying to generate sequences to test/learn how rx works or how you might make query X, use those subjects. If you find yourself using them intra-query, there is a CHANCE there is a better way.

Edit: realized I missed something:

Also, you ask if there is another way of raising stream events post-creation...the answer is yes; you might declare a stream via Create or Return or Generate that returns any old IObservable-based object that you define, which can also expose methods to inject events...or heck, have a lambda that spins a thread that checks a shared list that is routed to the return stream....I guess what I'm saying is that the possibilities are endless. There are something like a dozen "create a sequence of events"  methods declared on Observable - try them all!

EDIT 2:

An example? Sure, let's throw something together using `Observable.Create` that mimics a really inefficient `Subject`:

```
var running = true;
var values = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
var query = Observable.Create<int>(obs =>
{
    var body = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        while(running)
        {
            int nextValue;
            if(values.TryDequeue(out nextValue))
            {
                obs.OnNext(nextValue);
            }
            Thread.Yield();
        }
    });
    return Disposable.Create(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            running = false;
            body.Wait();
            obs.OnCompleted();            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            obs.OnError(ex);
        }
    });
});
using(query.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
{
    values.Enqueue(1);
    values.Enqueue(2);
    values.Enqueue(3);
    values.Enqueue(4);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Note that this is just quick-and-extremely-dirty example code. :)

Comment: yes that's what he was talking about I think - falling down to another IObservable is kind of chicken and egg :) - and involving shared list is adding state - what I'm trying to say if you have something that needs 'publishing' or you need a state (being a nature of what you do) you come down to similar solutions. Observable.Create (I do agree entirely) forces you to explore other things first - but is harder to get right at start.

Comment: May do post a simple sample about push new data after creation?

Comment: @Vincenzo Sure, just added a quick example

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do. There are cases for Subjects, but just not as many as one thinks when they first start out with Rx.

How will the new data enter your sequence? Will it be from another event? Perhaps a message from a communications framework? Maybe polling a file?

Depending on these answers you will normally find that you already have some sort of event source, and you are just converting to Rx from another pattern (Events, Polling, Callbacks etc...)

You also don't just have to use Observable.Create. You could use Observable.Timer/Interval to set up a polling sequence, Observable.FromEventPattern to leverage an existing Event, Observable.Start for a one off async task style calculation etc...

As Rx (or even Linq) can be quite abstract, asking abstract questions can often lead to very broad answers. If you give an indication of a problem you are trying to solve, that might help provide you with an even better answer.

Comment: The source is quite simple: I have several devices connected (network or serial communication) and every X minutes I get their state and associated data, then push (if not equal to previous one).

Comment: So you poll the device? If so then I would leverage a Scheduler or the Observable.Timer. This would negate the need for a Subject.

Comment: I think i have enough information to write some code and start tests. thank you a lot for your help,

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again but something is wrong!
The Interval and timer functinon generates auto observable with integer incremented each time...i would like to provide MY custom values!)

Comment: That is cool. Try using Select to map from the integer to your custom value. You can do thins like this; .Select(i=>myArray[i]) or just ignore the integer all together; .Select(_=>_factory.CreateThing()) -or- .Select(_=>bluetooth.GetStatus()). This will then allow you get your custom values at a constant rate based on the value you gave to the Timer/Interval method

Comment: Fantastic! Now i have the last question: what if in an iteration I have nothing to push (value is not changed)?

Comment: You can use DistinctUntilChanged() which will filter out repeated values.

Comment: Hello again and sorry for bother you again, but something is still wrong: here is the trouble.

Have please a look to this code: [link](http://nopaste.info/af046212ea.html)

So, when editing the value it is not pushed as new value, and nothing is displayed.
I noticed, debugging the Equals method, that when value is changed, the Equal function between the tag and itself is's on both side with new values!

Comment: You're right, but this textbox is limited and I was not able to write all needed information!

Comment: I'm going to try again.
I have a DataTag class and it's "key" is Name and Value, and i have a function that updates an IList<DataTag> into a class, where observable is held.

I want simply that, if a datatag key (name, value) changes, I want to be push-notified. So i wrote that piece of code [link](http://nopaste.info/af046212ea.html).
In the first part, Observable creation is shown: every x milliseconds call Update Function, get the Tags and select from Array as a single object.

In the second part the DataTag comparer class is shown to check only Name and WeakRawValue.

Comment: The problem is that when I change a value, I'm not push notified.
Inspecting the code, what I noticed is that the comparison function is always evaluating the same object.
I mean:
DataTag-> (Test1,1)
First push, ok, then wait some seconds...put a breakpoint and then change to (Test1,2). Continue debugging.
I never see comparision Test,1 and Test,2. I see directly and suddenly Test1,2 and Test1,2.

I hope this time I explained it better!

Comment: Sorry I still have no idea. I think you need to start a new question, enter all of the code (not just the tiny snippet in the link) and explain what you expected vs what you saw. The best would be to post the code + failing Unit tests for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving data from external device, you have no intention of signaling errors with `IObserver.OnError` (you assume your stream is endless and/or any problems with communications are within message itself), you poll at some rate, the only problem with Subject is that you will probably start polling this device even before anyone subscribes (but added benefit is that handling your state is pretty obvious, you created one object, it opened COM port, it communicates and publishes values)

Using `Observable.Create` or `Observable.Timer/Interval` might be better - but laziness is main reason, you will manage state anyway. And you will probably need to use Publish().RefCount() to prevent second subscription from opening port.